# Trouble with displaying products on a php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating an e-commerce website and making an ordering system however, with my code shown below, I get the error "data to render this page is missing". I have tried various work arounds but do not seam to get any further with this.

Could you please see if I am missing anything out or if there is a solution to this question?

At this stage I am trying to display my products from the sql database

Thank You for the help

```
 <?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['clothing_name'])) {
 // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "/xampp/htdocs/website/connection.php"; 

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE clothing_name='$clothing_name' LIMIT 1");
 $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
  // get all the clothing details
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $clothing_name = $row["clothing_name"];
    $size = $row["size"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $details = $row["details"];

         }

 } else {
  echo "That item does not exist.";
     exit();
 }

} else {
 echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
 exit();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Clearly your if statement is failing. And it's a simple if statement. `$_GET['clothing_name']` is not set. Find out why.

Comment: `/youtpage.php?clothing_name=1` you forgot to request `clothing_name`

Comment: @JohnConde, thanks for your reply. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers, thanks for the reply. I don't seem to understand what you are trying to say. Can you explain?

Comment: `$_GET['example']` in php can be defined by sent url only page.php?`example=blaaa` php will print `blaaa` if you do print echo `$_GET['exanple']`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
$clothing_name = $_GET['clothing_name'];
```

Update:

```
 <?php 
 // Script Error Reporting
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');

 // Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
 if (isset($_GET['clothing_name'])) {
 // Connect to the MySQL database  
 include "/xampp/htdocs/website/connection.php"; 
 $clothing_name = $_GET['clothing_name']; //HERE
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE clothing_name='".$clothing_name."' LIMIT 1");
 $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
 if ($productCount > 0) {
  // get all the clothing details
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
   $clothing_name = $row["clothing_name"];
   $size = $row["size"];
   $price = $row["price"];
   $details = $row["details"];

     }

   } else {
 echo "That item does not exist.";
 exit();
 }

} else {
echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
exit();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: where do I add the bit of code that you have provided?

Comment: Updated answer...line between include and if statement

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still not working out for me, I've tried loads of different things for the last few days and been searching on-line but cannot get this to work for me. Would you recommend anything else please? 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass a QueryString against which there are any records in your database. `$_GET[clothing_name]` will be set only if you provide it in your QueryString, since you are testing if `$_GET[clothing_name]` is set by method `isset()` so if you do not provide it in querystring condition will be false and you'll fall down to else condition.

Secondly define variable `$clothing_name` as you used it in your query before executing your SQLQuery.

`$clothing_name = $_GET['clothing_name'];`